# Url in android programming

Tags: android, url, https

I am new to android and Https (Url and al..)

I need to connect to url and if the connection is made that page will redirected to another url. Here I need to fetch that url and get a parameter from that url to use in another url.

How do I do this in android?? Please someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTTPRequest and return a JSON object.
You can learn more here

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/